# How to use preg_split for dividing unsigned numbers?

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I have a set of single or pair numbers as

```
9 (9)
-8 (-8)
1.1-2 (1.1 and 2)
-1-.2 (-1 and 0.2)
-1--3 (-1 and -3)
1--2 (1 and -2)
```

I want to split them to an array of two elements, as the second element can be empty.

I used `preg_split` to distinguish the `-` delimiter from the minus sign. The characteristic feature of the `-` delimiter is that it always preceded by a digit, thus, I tied

```
$numbers = preg_split("/\d[\-]/", $entry);
```

but this removes the digit before `-` too.

Comment: Try `preg_split("/(?<=\d)-/", $s)` or `preg_split("/\b-/", $s)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Add your solution as an answer to accept this

Comment: `-8 (-9)` How come `-9` from `-8`? Also, a simple `explode()`(with an tweak for second `-`)  with an implode of `and` works better.  Regex for this looks non sense to me.

Comment: @vivek_23 that was a typo :p